Reduce size of GeoJSON Multipolygon data
What I currently do:

Read .shp file using GeoPandas (Python), parse it to GeoJSON and write the data into MongoDB
(Create a 2D-Sphere Index on the collection for efficient querying.)
Query a subset of the data via HTTP (Python FastApi) from a React frontend application
Visualize the GeoJSON data on a leaflet map.

Problem:

The amount of data that has to be transported is big (might be > 1 GB depending on the area) which makes the user experience a nightmare.
I try to reduce the size of the data using the GeoPandas / Shapely simplify() function. That works to some degree, but not as good as hoped. I assume this is because the MultiPolygon consists of many tiny Polygons, which probably cannot be simplified any further (might consist of only four points).

The Question

Is there a way to combine multiple tiny polygons into bigger ones and thus making it more likely that the simplify() function will have a meaningful effect? To achieve this, I already tried to use the explode() function, which gives me a DataFrames of Polygons instead of a few MultiPolygon and then apply unary_union(). Sadly, this gives me roughly the same result as the original data. That leads me to the assumption that the polygons might be in such a fragmented state that does not allow for any combination of those, since they share not common edges.

Is there any other way to reduce the size of the geometries / GeoJSON data or improve transport?


Edit: The data represents flooding areas and is split into different polygons depending on the water depth on a discrete scale. All analysis is done in the backend before any simplification. The frontend should only provide a visual layer for explanation. Small imperfections would be acceptable.

Have you tried geojson-shave?

The answer will depend a bit on the sourcing of the shapefile and how much control you have over it.
If you're able to work with the shapefile before import, then you might try a service like mapshaper (https://mapshaper.org/) to simplify the shapefile before ingest. Or you might load the layer into software like QGIS to work with it more manually. It might be helpful to know what type of geometry is being presented (counties, states, countries, census blocks, etc.) to understand what the options might be. One of the issues with simplification is that the simplification process does not always preserve edges...you could easily go from two features that share a border to two features with a gap or overlap.
I'm not an expert on geometry data storage, but my gut is that you may be hurting yourself a little bit by relying on a text-based geometry format for transport rather than a binary format. I took a shapefile I had and ran it through GeoPandas to convert it to GeoJSON and the size went from 279MB as a .shp file to 936MB as a GeoJSON file.
Depending on your use case, you might also determine how critical it is to represent your data with polygons. Point geometry could be sufficient.

You're right that text-based transport increases the file size, but it makes it way easier to handle the data. I need to be able to perform geospatial querying, which would probably require me to store GeoJSON data in the DB, and parse it binary on the server before sending it to the client. This should be easy enough, though parsing it on the client side and adding it to the leaflet map will be a bit more complex as far as I understand. I added some details to my question concerning the data. I will try your suggestions asap

With the additional information, what you might consider is rendering your analysis data as a raster on the backend and serving a PNG image to the frontend. This would depend on how interactive the presentation is supposed to be. If it's just a quick visualization, that might be enough. It could also open up leveraging APIs that provide base maps that this layers on top of. Even if there are some pan-and-zoom features, it might still work...people are generally used to a slight rendering delay when using tools like Google Maps.

To your response, it depends on the DB you use. PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension handles this in binary format with no problem, and GeoPandas is set up to interface with PostGIS.

Since the map should be interactive, I can't rely on static images. But I've seen solutions, that use map tiles as a layer to display such data. Saldy though that's too complex for my usage.  I just tried to simplify the shapes using mapshaper.org. While simplify here really has a big impact on file size (and details), I realized that it allows me to export the data to TopoJSON. While still text-based, that reduced the amount in one example by a factor of 5. I think I will try a combination of manual preprocessing / simplification of the shp file and dig deeper into TopoJSON. Thanks!
